# Gcc not found : cannot compile c program in a Buildroot image for STM32MP

Tags: compiling, make, c, gcc, buildroot

I'm trying to compile a C program with `gcc` in a image that I have made with `buildroot` for STM32mp157a-dk1, but I get:

```
$ gcc bl.c -o bl
-sh: gcc: not found
$
```

gcc is installed on the system; version 9.3.

Comment: Then it's not in your environment. Add the output of `whereis gcc` to your question.

Comment: Run the command in the terminal and edit the question to include the output.